# How can I make my white LED strip light warmer?

Tags: led

I recently bought warm white LED strips and installed them. Even though they are considered "warm" white (3000K), the light is very white and not close to incandescent light and it hurts the eyes.

Is there any way to make the light warmer? maybe hacks like painting the strip LED's?

Comment: Spec warmer LED strips. It's a function of the semiconductor doping and the phosphor used in the LED optics. Works the same way as fluorescent tubes, you can't change the spectrum after it's generated.

Answer (score 1):

The cheapest, laziest way (that would actually work) is to obtain some [**cinematic gels**](https://youtu.be/cAX6KFWxzCM?t=1m40s) (they are sheets), such as those made by Rosco.   Cut them into strips or squares, affix any way practical.

The better, long term approach is to spec better LED strips.  LED strips come in a huge range of product qualities.  By and large, consumers either pay waaaaay too much for mediocre quality strips (I've seen companies charge $90/metre with a straight face), or very low prices ($7 per 5 metre roll) for "fell off a truck in Shenzhen China" quality strips.  Either one may have poor accounting for CRI, overall brightness, etc.

Aside from color temperature, there is also CRI (Color Rendering Index), a percentage scale of how close to natural or tungsten light it is.  CRI is compensated for what *human eyes see*, so a light can be quite uneven on a spectrum analyzer and still have a very high CRI.  Machine eyes don't see light the way human eyes do, which may be a problem if machine eyes are involved.

Comment: How do I find a high quality led strip? Are there known brands or types? What specific characteristics to look for?

Comment: I think only experience... avoid the cheapest ones, and try the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is any paint which will shift the spectrum to that region, but some insulation adhesive tape will certainly help.

Kapton insulation tape will block blue component from the white light and makes it more warmer. See http://www.kaptontape.com